# REACT npm run start - adding extra custom files

Tags: reactjs

How custom files can be added in REACT server running in local deploy mode?
`npm run start`
in browser page opened and works as expected: for example **http://192.168.11.240:3005/mode/weight**
Now I want add custom files like **io.cfg** and have http access to it from web browser: **http://192.168.11.240:3005/mode/weight/io.cfg**
Where and how it must be described and where file io.cfg must be placed?

I guess it must be added to **package.json** file but I was unable to find correct solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.